# Retrieve text from search box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a program that allows me to search a document to see how many times a word appears within that document. I would like to choose which word to search by entering the desired word into a search box that I've built. Currently, If I hard code the word that I'm searching for, it'll search the document and tell me how times it appears. If I try to use the search box to enter a word, I always get a result of 0. I need a way to retrieve the word entered from the search box and use that word as the word that I want to check.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WordBubble</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wordbubble.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="search">
    Search Word: <input type="search" name="Wordsearch" size="35">
    <button type="submit" class ="searchme">Search</button>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".searchme").click(function(){
      var myWord = $ (this).text();
      findDuplicates();
    });
  });

  // ajax call to get comments document
  function findDuplicates (myWord) {
    $.get( "comm.txt", function( text ) {


      words = text.split(' '),
      sortedWords = words.slice(0).sort(),
      duplicateWords = []



    for (var i=0; i<sortedWords.length-1; i++) {
        if (myWord == sortedWords[i]) {
          duplicateWords.push(sortedWords[i]);
        }
    }

    $( "p" ).html(duplicateWords.length);
  });
}
</script>

<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click-handler you retrieve the searchstring from the button instead from the input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".searchme").click(function(){
    // get the word from the input
    var myWord = $('input').val();
    findDuplicates(myWord);
  });
});
```